# Hair emitting from wrong side of mesh

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, mirror, hair

[image]I made a head using the mirror modifier, and for the hair duplicated the scalp so I could add hair particles across the whole head and not just the side that I had sculpted the actual mesh. I flipped the half of the scalp using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> along the X axis, and joined the two halves together into one object. When I went to add hair particles though, all the hair particles coming from the mirrored side were facing inwards.

After a bit of googling around, I though it might be that the normals had become flipped, and that was causing the hair to grow inwards. However, flipping the normals did not seem to change anything in regards to the hair.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your error and, unless there is some baked cache for Hair Dynamics, my hair seem to always update to the new normals. Are you 100% sure that your normals are now correct? Can you share part of your file or some screenshots (you can do it by editing your question)?

Comment: Also: does an entirely new particlesystem on your mesh behave in the wrong way, or is the error only happening to a particular set of hair created before fixing the normals?

Comment: Sometimes it helps to check "use modifier stack" under "emission" in the particle tab. Sometimes it fixes hiccups like this.

Answer (score 0):

I just dealt with this. Check your Timing panel and make sure the ending is set to 1.0

Hope this helps. It did it for me.